# How can I combine or push an array into an existed array?

Tags: php, arrays

Now I have an array looks like this

```
Array([0] => array([region]=>1[district]=>2[sell]=>3)
      [1] => array([region]=>1[district]=>3[sell]=>6)
      [2] => array([region]=>1[district]=>4[sell]=>9)
     )
```

And I have an other array look like this

```
Array([0] => array([buy]=>3)
      [1] => array([buy]=>4)
      [2] => array([buy]=>5)
     )
```

So the question is how can i combine two array to make it looks like this ?
or is there any method to push the second array into the first array?

```
Array([0] => array([region]=>1[district]=>2[sell]=>3[buy]=>3)
      [1] => array([region]=>1[district]=>3[sell]=>6[buy]=>4)
      [2] => array([region]=>1[district]=>3[sell]=>9[buy]=>5)
     )
```

Comment: I think you should use `foreach` to combine you want.

Comment: Does the other array ever have more than one row?

Comment: You could just change the way you arrange the array and then use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: @Ja͢ck Yes, both of them have more than one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$existing = array(
    0 => array('region'=>1, 'district'=>2, 'sell'=>3),
    1 => array('region'=>4, 'district'=>5, 'sell'=>6),
    2 => array('region'=>5, 'district'=>8, 'sell'=>9),
);

$newItems = array(
    0 => array('buy'=>3),
    1 => array('buy'=>4),
    2 => array('buy'=>5)
);

foreach($newItems as $i => $data){
    $key = array_pop(array_keys($data));
    $value = array_pop(array_values($data));
    $existing[$i][$key] = $value;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($existing); echo '</pre>';
```

#### [PhpFiddle Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ada8be3415b29e84c69c)

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget about functional programming.

```
$existing = [
    ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3],
    ['a' => 4, 'b' => 5, 'c' => 6],
    ['a' => 5, 'b' => 8, 'c' => 9],
];
$newItems = [
    ['d' => 3],
    ['d' => 4],
    ['d' => 5]
];
// let's run over those arrays and do array_merge over items
$result = array_map('array_merge', $existing, $newItems);
var_dump($result);
```

P.S. There is exist more simple way using [array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/array_replace_recursive)

```
$result2 = array_replace_recursive($existing, $newItems);
```

Comment: You should mention that `[]` can only be used in PHP 5.4 and above.

Comment: I would probably have used `array_replace()` but this is a clean way of doing things.